# What word to use: reject, disapprove, overrule, throw away, rebuke or wave aside? (American English)

Tags: word-choice, american-english

First of all, is this an American English or an English English question site?

Then my actual question:
There is a list of opinions and semi facts. I do not agree with some of the given opinions and semi facts in this list.
What word do I use to describe what I do: reject, disapprove, overrule, throw away, rebuke or wave aside?
I don't know the corrct word to use, because it's both opinions and semi-facts that I have to cover with this word.
Thank you for helping me.

(Note: I am not a native speaker. I would like to learn American English)

Comment: I'd selectively reject some of the assertions.

Comment: We deal with all types of English. It is OK to request answers from a particular perspective such as AmE, but in this case, I doubt if it is necessary.

Comment: *Dismiss* is also possible: I would dismiss some of the assertions.

Comment: Yes,I think I was looking for the verb ' to dismiss'. Thank you!
(Thank you both!)
Could you put the word 'rebuke' in a sentence, so I can see how that is used?

Comment: *Rebuke* basically means *reprimand*, so it would be used for whoever made the list, not the items on the list itself. "*I **rebuked** the list-makers for including half-truths and personal grudges.*"

Comment: @Mick Agreed, that's precisely the word I'd use.

Answer (score 0):

Overrule only really applies if you have some sort of power and that it was a ruling to begin with. You could use refute or rebuke if you have a counter argument. Disapprove implies that you have the power to approve (for example if I wanted to say to my students, 'these are opinions and semi-facts that I don't want you using to support your thesis', I could say I disapprove of them). None of the words really cover your 'disapproval' of the subjectivity of the facts, so you may need to expand upon whichever word you choose. Perhaps you could a bit more context?